# HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm running into this error when trying to hit any of the Organizations Lookup API endpoints:

`HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee`

I also run into this error for the Organization Search API. Which is strange because my "Usage and Limits" console says that these requests were successful. I've tried emailing `LMSdeveloperteam@linkedin.com` about this error but have gotten no response back.

Here is the permissions my app currently has: [permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Bxs.png)

And here is my "Usage and Limits" screen: [requests console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp77f.png)

There are a number of v2 endpoints that I am able to access successfully and we already have API access so I'm drawing a blank on what else to do other than continue to email `LMSdeveloperteam@linkedin.com` and post here.

Does anyone have any ideas? LinkedIn support could you look into this please?

Comment: linkedin support is normally not active on stackoverflow.

Comment: What avenue would you recommend to contact them? On their support page: https://developer.linkedin.com/support it lists StackOverflow as a resource to get in contact with their support.

Comment: there are 2 things you could try and those are :
 https://help.linkedin.com or https://twitter.com/linkedinhelp

Answer (score 0):

can you verify that you have an ADMINISTRATOR account in atleast one organization ?

> Depending on your application's permissions, some Organization API
>   requests may require the authenticated member have a specific
>   organization role type, such as ADMINISTRATOR. You may lookup access
>   control information either by member or organizational entity.

could you also try if you have another api call from organization to look if you have access to the organization api ?

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/{organization ID}
```

Comment: So the credential I'm using has to have an ADMINSTRATOR account at that organization for some of these endpoints to work? I'll reach out to one of my cilents to ensure they have that.  

I tried this endpoint `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations?q=vanityName&vanityName=Linkedin` as is and with my vanity-name and I get the same `HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url` error.  

I also tried `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/{organization ID}` and got the same `HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url` error.

Comment: then the only thing i can think of is that you do not have the right permissions.

what you could try is look at the manage company pages API.
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages
it is the V1 version of organizations.

Comment: We are using the manage company pages API in production, we have no trouble making requests to that API.

Comment: And I've confirmed that the credential I'm testing with has ADMINISTRATOR accounts at their organization and the credential I'm using is associated with a ADMINISTRATOR account.

Comment: can you confirm that you can reach the organization api with your current partner program.

Comment: I cannot access any endpoints in this documentation: `https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/organizations/organization-lookup-api` or `https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/organizations/organization-search`, or `https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/organizations/organization-access-control`. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: well if they all give a 403 error then im sure that you do not have the correct partnership for this api.

Comment: Cool thanks Lars, I'll email `LMSdeveloperteam@linkedin.com` again and ask for partnership access to the organizations API